# Navigation to Main Activity through child activity started from widget

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-navigation

I'm working on some application where I would like to implement same pattern of accessing to main activity of application as Gmail app has. Here's a picture from [Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#into-your-app):

[image]

Basically I already done everything about clicking and things like that, the problem is when I press home button or back hardware button. The first one (home button) starts code in onOptionsItemSelected, but for the second (back hardware button) I don't know how to override it. Here's the code with which I was trying to achieve the same pattern as Gmail app has:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.

EDIT: Hardware button action can be overridden with onBackPresed() method, thanks to mansoulx and Jack. One part of the problem is solved, but I still didn't figure out how to achieve same pattern as Gmail app with Intents.

EDIT 2: I implemented the same code as on [Android Developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#BuildBackStack) but it still doesn't work. I added negation to IF statement of that code and then the wanted pattern started working, but with wrong animation (animation that is used when you change application from multitask menu). I don't think that this is right, so I am still looking for help. That's the code I used (without negation):

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
            if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
                TaskStackBuilder.create(this).addNextIntentWithParentStack(upIntent).startActivities();
            } else {
                NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
            }
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override back button by overriding Activity.onBackPressed().

You can also check this link out to implement back navigation.
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html

Answer to EDIT2:
It is not recommended behavior, but I personally do something like:

parentActivity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, childactivity.class).putExtra("return", true));
```

childActivity.onBackPress:

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("return", false))
    super.onBackPress();
else {
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), parentactivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
}
```

Comment: remember to remove **super** if you want to use onBackPressed()

Comment: I implemented the code for "Navigate up with a new back stack" and it still doesn't work. Please look at my EDIT 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(

    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // code for Up button click
        break;

    return  super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    super.onBackPressed();
    // code for Back button
}
```

This [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Home) may help you.

Comment: Thanks for partial solution, but the problem with returning from child activity still exists. Look at edited content.

Comment: the link in my answer explains how you can make an activity be a parent for another one. Thus, calling `finish` on a child will open it's parent from stack.

Comment: I did everything that is needed to achieve the same as it's covered on that link, but it still doesn't work at all. If I start activity through widget and then click Up button, I'm back to the home screen and widget. I want to go back to the application's main activity which is parent of activity of which I access through widget.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with this code in the IntentService of the widget:

```
Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, ChildActivity.class);
PendingIntent clickPendingIntentTemplate = TaskStackBuilder.create(getBaseContext())
        .addNextIntentWithParentStack(launchIntent)
        .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

view.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, clickPendingIntentTemplate);
```